# Executemany on pyodbc only return result from last parameter

Tags: python-2.7, oracle11g, pyodbc

I have a problem when I try to use pyodbc executemany function.
I have an Oracle database and I want to extract data for multiple days.

I cannot use between in my request, because the database is not indexed on the date field and its taking forever.
I want to manually ask all day and process answers.
I cannot thread this part, so I wanted to use `executemany` to get rows more quickly.

The problem is when I use `executemany` I only got the result of the last argument asked.

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_11_2};DBQ=dbname;UID=uid;PWD=pwd')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT date FROM table WHERE date = TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/YYYY')"
query_args = (
                 ('29/04/2016',),
                 ('28/04/2016',),
)
cursor.executemany(query, query_args)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

In rows, I can only find rows with `(datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 28, 0, 0), )`.
Always the last argument.

I am using python 2.7.9 from WinPython on a Oracle database with a client on 11.0.2.
Except this query, every other query is perfectly fine.

I cannot use `IN ()` synthax for 2 reasons:

- I want to limit operations on database side, and do most of thing on script side (I've tried but it's way too long)
- I might have more than 1000 different dates in the request.

(Right now I'm using IN() OR IN() OR IN()... but if anyone find something better that would be wonderful !)

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Your query runs once with one argument. If you want to run for multiple dates either use "IN" clause, this will require to modify query_args a bit.

```
  "SELECT date FROM table WHERE date in (TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))"

 query_args = (
             ('29/04/2016','28/04/2016'),
 )
```

or cursor through each date argument:

```
while query_arg in query_args:
  cursor.executemany(query, query_arg )
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: That's true I can do that but as I said, I want to limit operations on database side because it's taking too much time on my database, I want to process things on script side, that's why I want to use executemany. You can use `execute` for your request, you don't need `executemany`.